# Children's song about the onomatopoeia of the wind

Tags: identification-request, song-lyrics

When I was a young child (probably somewhere between 1985 to 1995), I remember watching a cartoon involving anthropomorphic animals (I don't remember which animals other than that I think one was a monkey. They were all approximately the same size and basically had human proportions other than having animal heads) where they sang a song about the wind with the following verse:

> Oo-oo-oo-oo-ooh went the wind one day
> We all listened carefully to see what it would say
> Ooh ooh oo-oo-oo-oo
> Ooh ooh oo-oo-oo-oo

For some reason, that bit has stuck in my head for decades, to the point where I still find myself singing it during times of high wind to my son, but searching bits of the verse I remember turn up no hits, and I find myself wondering what the other verses might be.

The only other bit I remember from the cartoon involved the characters singing a song with nonsense syllables and doing a choreographed dance in a line-up which at some point involved them leaning to one side and rhythmically extending one hand and the opposite leg to the beat of the song like they were reaching sideways.

If it would help, I could actually sing the song as I remember it.

https://youtube.com/shorts/2DQEDRlDTyA

Comment: Upvoted for the linked video with the singing. We need more multimedia-enhanced questions!

Comment: It might turn out not useful at all but just in case, searching for "went the wind one day" in Google Books brings up "The Magic of Music, book two", perhaps the book has the title of the song, perhaps Google incorrectly assumes I am searching for some partial match there.

Comment: [The contents of the book in Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Magic_of_Music_Book_2/_Cf5Ty5WVI4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the+magic+of+music&printsec=frontcover), assuming we're referring to the same one, looks to be entirely instrumental.

Comment: No, I meant that one: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Magic_of_Music/FKAQAQAAMAAJ  Sadly, no snippets view.